# How to fix positioning of expiry / CVC / ZIP

Tags: css, stripe-payments

I have created a Stripe Elements card form on my website, but I'm having some trouble with it. Right now, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the expiry and CVC inputs are squashed into one another.

If I fill them out, then the ZIP input is out of the frame.

[image]

It seems like this is because I have added letter-spacing to the placeholder element when defining the style for my card element.

```
var style = {
  base: {
    color: "#fff",
    fontFamily: '"Source Sans Pro", sans-serif',
    textTransform: "uppercase",
    fontSize: '12px',
    iconColor: "#bbb",
    lineHeight: "37px",
    maxHeight: "37px",
    verticalAlign: "middle",
    letterSpacing: "0.5px",
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#bbb',
      fontFamily: '"Source Sans Pro", sans-serif',
      letterSpacing: "2px",
    },
    '::selection': {
      color: '#fff',
      backgroundColor: '#333',
    }
  }
};
```

Removing the letter-spacing from ::placeholder resolves the issue, but I would really like to keep it in order to align with the style of the rest of my website.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the result of the mismatch between your main `letterSpacing` and `::placeholder` `letterSpacing` values; if you make the `base.letterSpacing` value also `2px` it seems to work (though it does temporarily push CVC off the side).